# Accept only one or more files in html form

Tags: html, forms, input

I use these codes for creating a form which accept one or more files. not zero files.

```
<form id="uploader">
  <input type="file">
  <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

but it's not working. How can I do that?

Comment: How it's not working? There is no validation in your code.

Comment: Please go read [ask] first of all.

Comment: there is no validation in your code. And to select multi files you just need to add `<input type="file" multiple="multiple" />` and in form tag ` enctype="multipart/form-data"`
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `required` and `multiple` attributes in your input field.

```
<input type="file" required multiple>
```

---

Example:

```html
<form id="uploader">
  <input type="file" required multiple>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

To select multiple files, hold down the CTRL or SHIFT key while selecting.

use  `multiple` attribute.

```html
 

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Problem</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Insert form here -->
    <form id="uploader">
    <input type="file" multiple>
    <button type="submit"></button>
    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```